How to automate the Crafter in Minecraft Bedrock?
I'm trying to make an auto pumpkin pie machine using the crafter in Bedrock survival. I have the auto pumpkin, sugar cane and egg collectors set up already. I don't know how to get them into the crafter in a way that allows the automatic production of pumpkin pie. Ingredients don't stack when moved into the crafter from the hopper unless there are no other slots left so ingredients end up taking more slots than they're supposed to. I'm assuming I have to be using comparators to move the ingredients into the crafter in a specific order but I don't know how to do that. I can't find an actual tutorial for this on YouTube.

Hi Jex, can you please post screenshots or descriptions of your current setup (by [edit]ing your question)?
